# Counting letter occurances Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, character, histogram

I am trying to count letter occurances and print them. This is what i have so far:

```
def histogram(L):
    d = {}
    for x in L:
      for letter in x:
        if letter in d:
          d[letter] += 1
        else:
          d[letter] = 1
    for i in range(len(d)):
      print('{} | {}'.format(d, d[i])) # GETTING ERRORS ON THIS LINE
    return d
histogram(open('cipher.txt'))
```

For some reason i am getting errors on that line. How would i print it correctly?

EDIT:solution my Martijn! Props! but does anyone know how to sort the dictionary by alphabetical order?

Comment: **What** errors are you getting?

Comment: `d` is a dict, you're trying to index it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` is a *dictionary*, not a list. Loop over the keys:

```
for key in d:
    print('{} | {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```

or you'll get `KeyError` exceptions.

You may be interested in the [`collections.Counter()` class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); it's a counting dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter

def histogram(L):
    d = Counter(letter for line in L for letter in x)
    for letter in d:
        print('{} | {}'.format(letter, d[letter]))
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks, just one thing... How would i print the actual character like it prints the d[key] correctly but when it goes to print d it just prints the entire dictionary..

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: Print `key` instead.

Comment: oh wait im so stupid... Thanks! will be accepting and upvoting ASAP

Comment: Last thing, how do i alphabetically sort the print? Or sort the dictionary in alphabetical order? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: `sorted(d)` lists the keys in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, lets simplify your code. You can use a set() on the initial string to get a list of the unique characters, then just use the count method of the list.

```
def histogram(L):
    d = {letter:L.count(letter) for letter in set(L)}
    for key in d:
        print "{} | {}".format(key, d[key]}
```

Comment: This is incredibly inefficient and assumes `L` is a list of just letters.